# $L^p$-exercise with a "sign" function

Tags: real-analysis

Let $(X,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ such that $1<p<\infty$ and $1/p+1/q=1$ holds. For $f\in L^p(X,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ such that $f\neq0$ define

$g(x):=c(sign(f(x))|f(x)|^{p-1},\qquad c=||f||_p^{-p/q}$ where

$sign(x) = 1$ if $x>0$ $sign(x)= 0$ if $x=0$ and $sign(x)=-1$ if $x<0$.

Show that $g\in L^q(X,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ and $\int f\cdot g d\mu = ||f||_p$

Well the fact that $1/p+1/q=1$ strongly suggests to use Holders inequality somehow. Also I'm generally confused about what to do with this weird $sign$ function.